# What Rails module or gem does set default response headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, passenger, rack

With empty Rails app I have `Cache-Control` set to `max-age=0, private, must-revalidate` by default.

I want to understand this process better so I am trying to detect code that does this job.

I have checked `actionpack`, `rake middleware`, `config.action_dispatch.default_headers`, `initializers and envinronment configs`.

I am using Rails 4.2, nginx as web server and Passenger as application server.

Possibly this is some rack middleware or application server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rack::ETag` sets default `Cache-Control` header.[image]